# Datatables Search Option

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables for table .I want to search based on the name column only but by default it search based on all column.I want to search based on name only any help should be appreciated.[image]

Js-code

```
$('#table-filter').dataTable({
"bDestroy": true,
"bPaginate": true,
"bProcessing": false,
 "bStateSave": false,
 "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, 50, 100 , -1], [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
 "iDisplayLength" : 5,
 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

 "aoColumnDefs": [
  { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0,1,7,8 ] }
        ],
"oLanguage": {
                 "sUrl": baseUrl+"/media/language/dt/"+lang_code+".txt",
             }
  })
```

Comment: Why don't you try **[Column Filter](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customFilters.html)**

Comment: @bios I am using Column Filter for all the column. Current time it is disabled and now we have show only search box which search only on name column basis. If i use column filter then also hard to show on header(On search box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I hope this will help you:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": true, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1] },
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 2] },
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 3] }
    ] } );
```

**[Example](http://live.datatables.net/iyuvew/edit#javascript,html,live)**

Or

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1,2,3,4 ] }      

    ] } );
```

**[Example](http://live.datatables.net/iyuvew/2/edit)**

here is the **[API Documentation for columns](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#)**

Answer (score 1):

According to [***Datatables document***](http://datatables.net/ref#bSearchable)

```
// Using aoColumnDefs
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ] } );
} );


// Using aoColumns
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSearchable": false },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ] } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use the [Yet Another DataTables Column Filter - (yadcf)](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) (I wrote it)

You can use the autocomplete filter type and you can place it anywhere you want in your page, code sample:

```
$('#table-filter').dataTable({...}).yadcf(
    [
        {
          column_number : 2, 
          filter_type: "auto_complete",
          filter_container_id: "external_filter_container"
        }
    ]);
```

where `external_filter_container` is an id of `div`/`span` that you want to place the filter

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own input search.

1.- Input Search html:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 dataTables_filter">
    <div class="dataTables_filter">
     <label style="float:right;">
      <fmt:message key="provider.search.name"/>
      <input id="colNameSearch_filter" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
```

After write in the input html thrown a function.

```html
$('#colNameSearch_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
        filterColumn(1);
    } );
```

And that is the function that we call.

```html
function filterColumn ( i ) {
    $('#tableResponse').DataTable().column( i ).search(
        $('#colNameSearch_filter').val()
    ).draw();
}
```